# I can't import any mesh

Tags: mesh, import

So I'm new to Blender, like only a few days new. And I have no idea why but, when I download any mesh file, and import it, it either says "Invalid Heading" or doesn't appear at all. Again, I have really no idea.. and I feel discouraged.

Comment: can you upload an example on a non-importable mesh? is it maybe just really tiny or something? this question is so broad i don't really know where to start..

Comment: Not sure, I've tried scaling up and scaling down, yet nothing. Here's the model.. uh thing. https://filebin.net/x4b2nxssdcfzf7yi

Comment: i just had to zoom way out (it's big and off to the side). https://imgur.com/rMvjKCB

Comment: Make sure that you use *File > Import* and **not** *File > Open*. The latter is for Blender project files only (. blend files).

Comment: I still can't find it, like it doesn't exist. I see it in the scene collection though, but like I said, it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: Zoom out. its there is just way off to the side; alternatively, you should be able to select it in the collection, hit tab to enter edit mode and either scale it down (eg, s + .1 ) or reset the origin to 0,0,0